# Difficulty to run a java program

Tags: java

I'm having troubles running the helloworldapp java program everytime i use the cmd.Here is the original execution of the program.

---

```
C:\Users\char>cd\

C:\>cd program files

C:\Program Files>cd java

C:\Program Files\Java>cd helloworldapp

C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>path=c:\\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin

C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>javac helloworldapp
error: Class names, 'helloworldapp', are only accepted if annotation processing
is explicitly requested
1 error

C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp> >>
```

And everytime I try to correct the class name it is saying the same thing. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @ChrisCooney: and you're duplicate your comment..:D

Comment: I know. Oh the irony.

Comment: You should refer to some tutorial or book as this question doesn't require any kind of RND to be done. How to get started guide would have definitely helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>javac helloworldapp.java
```

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html

> If you receive this error, you forgot to include the .java suffix when compiling the program. Remember, the command is javac HelloWorldApp.java not javac HelloWorldApp.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>javac helloworldapp.java
```

Instead:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>javac helloworldapp
```

Reference : [Lesson: Common Problems (and Their Solutions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact the you haven't specified the .java file-extension.

**Correct usage:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>javac helloworldapp.java
```

The .class file will now be generated. To run it, use (without the extension this time):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>java helloworldapp
```

Using the .class extension here will again cause you problems.

**The following usage is incorrect:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\HelloWorldApp>java helloworldapp.class
```